# Switching source and destination (or undoing the mv, cp operation)

Tags: bash, rename, cp, function

`mv` or `cp` commands both expect source and destination as arguments.

In case you want to undo the change you made, or just change the source and destination you supplied before, what is the quickest way to do this?

I thought of creating a function that takes `command src dest` and switching `src` and `dest`, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: `mv bar foo` isn't necessarily the inverse of `mv foo bar`, depending on if you overwrote an existing file, and `cp bar foo` definitely isn't the inverse of `cp foo bar`

Comment: Yes, but I am careful to use absolute path when using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a way using `cp` and `mv`, but using a feature of `GNU bash` with `readline` with the usual (`emacs`-like) keybindings:

Just like in `emacs`, you can transpose words with M-t (meta-, alt-), so if you're using bash, undoing `mv file_a file_b` could be as simple as pressing the up arrow and hitting M-t, which changes the above to `mv file_b file_a`.

(Now this isn't even a proper solution, I don't know whether this will work when the arguments to `mv` have spaces or other less usual, special characters. And, just like +Michael Mrozek said, it's not possible to undo `cp` this way. For a real undo, you also have to define *exactly* what you mean by "undo" (for example, what if `cp` overwrites an existing file? there will be no way to undo it unless you wrap `cp` around something that keeps backup copies!))

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank You.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to make the space as the delimiter?

Comment: @Prometheus, no, I have no idea. Although readline has an init file, I can't find a setting for the delimiter in the manual.